# Path selection constraints not working as expected

Tags: circuit, protocol, consensus, myfamily

From [Section 2.2](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/path-spec.txt#n197) of the path specification

> We do not choose any router in the same family as another in the same
>       path. (Two routers are in the same family if each one lists the other
>       in the "family" entries of its descriptor.)

On more than one occasion I've had to manually create a [`NodeFamily`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#NodeFamily) from the results of [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/). In each case the node has a family but appears to ignore it during path selection. That is, until I create the family manually. This occurs with [`StrictNodes`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes) using Tor v0.2.5.10.

In a related incident, despite the use of [`StrictNodes`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes), an exit was used which violated constraints put into effect. Now I can understand being flexible in choosing to violate (some) constraints. If I say I don't want an exit to be used and I use [`StrictNodes`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes), then the exit shouldn't be used.

Should I be concerned or is there a good reason for this to occur?

Comment: Dear Leeroy, The link [3] points to content of link [2], Thus to "NodeFamily node,node,..." not to "StrictNodes 0|1". Warm Regards

Comment: Oh thanks! I guess editing others comments became taboo while I was away. I shall have to remember that ;P

Answer (score 1):

Based on setting strict nodes and having an exit show up which violates this constraint I would (now) be inclined to search for a bug. Had just the family constraint been violated I might see this as a situation where Tor decided to default on path selection. That does occur -- it just seemed extreme to ignore node family. On the other hand, ignoring the node family isn't a huge deal. These nodes are precisely the ones that put the effort into identifying their relations. I'd be more worried about unidentified relations.

Combined the two issues point to a bug which should be reproduced.

I didn't see an existing ticket so I'll start by writing some code to investigate the problem over time. Then I can reproduce the problem or at least inspect the internal state at the time of failure. As it stands this doesn't appear to occur frequently.